# Display value in css not working as expected

Tags: html, css

The HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="hidden">Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code

```
.shown {
    display: hidden;
}
```

When this code is run the heading is still displayed. Why is this happening. I thought the display value of hidden would hid the element from the normal flow of the page.

Comment: There is no such property `display:hidden` in css... Take a look at that [CSS display on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: Consider searching google for allowed values of css property `display`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hidden` is not a valid value for display, you are after `none`. Also, your class name is incorrect, it should be `.hidden`

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Also, there is another property called `visibility` that also hides content with `visibility: hidden`. The difference is `display` makes it appear as the element has been removed completely from the page, whereas `visibility` makes the content disappear, but the space the element occupies is still respected.

Comment: First person to have highlighted *both* of the issues here. +1

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have messed up the values of two different CSS attributes i.e. `visibility` and `display`.

### display

```
.class_name
{
    display:none;
}
```

Setting the `display` as `none` causes the object not to be visible and along with that the space required by the object is not alloted i.e. ***the invisible object doesn't occupy any space***.

### visibility

```
.class_name
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Setting the `visibility` as `hidden` causes the object not to be visible but the space required by the object is alloted i.e. ***it occupies the space it requires although it's not visible***.

**[Reference](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong class try this

```
<h1 class="shown">Hello World</h1>
```

and css

```
.shown {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
 .hidden{
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.shown {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
 .shown {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your css tag name is mismatching to your HTML code. And your CSS is wrong as well.

You could either write display: none or visibility: hidden.